# Effective Programming to calculate BMI in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and in beginning stage too. I wrote a program to calculate BMI with the help of couple of topics in here.

Code review:Its that i have used main function thrice in the program and i think writing bmi formula can also be little more efficient i.e., avoiding cast of float to variables. so please suggest efficient writing of the same code.

Also i'm learning ptyhon from https://automatetheboringstuff.com, if you could please suggest best way to learn python online.
Here is my code:

```
import re
print('Calculate your body mass index(BMI) today.')
def main():

    while True:
        myName = input('Enter your name:')
        if re.match('^[a-z, A-Z, ,]*$', myName):
            print ('Nice to meet you, ' + myName)
            return
        else:
            print ('You should enter a to z letters only!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
def main():
    while True:
        global height
        height = input('Enter your height in cms: ')
        if re.match('^[0-9]*$', height):
            return
       else:
            print ('You should enter 0 to 9 letters only!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
def main():
    while True:
        global weight
        weight = input('Enter your weight in kgs: ')
        if re.match('^[0-9]*$', weight):
            return
        else:
            print ('You should enter 0 to 9 letters only!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
bmi = round((float (weight)/ (0.0001*float(height)*float(height))), 2)
minIdealWeight = round(18.5*0.0001*float(height)*float(height), 2)
maxIdealWeight = round(25*0.0001*float(height)*float(height), 2)
if 18.5<bmi<25:
        print('Your BMI is '+str(bmi)+'.' '\n Maintain your weight, you\'re normal.')
elif bmi<18.5:
        print('Your BMI is '+str(bmi)+'.' '\nGain some weight, you\'re underweight.')
        print('Your ideal weight is between '+str(minIdealWeight)+' to ' +str(maxIdealWeight)+' kgs.')
else:
        print('Your BMI is '+str(bmi)+'.' '\nLoose some weight, you\'re overweight.')
        print('Your ideal weight is between '+str(minIdealWeight)+' to ' +str(maxIdealWeight)+' kgs.')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); your current question is a little vague.  What are your specific efficiency requirements?  Show benchmarking data and targets, also what you've tried so far.  For that matter, what do you mean by "efficient"?  In general, make your question as specific as possible.  That'll maximize your chance of getting a good, speedy answer. Having said all that, this question might be better for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you are just beginning to learn programming, I suggest to start with something easier. The site you are using is OK, but take it step by step, and don't jump to more complex stuff before you've mastered the very basics. Regular expressions is more than basics !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at

- Using a class (helps remove global variables)
- Using Command line switches
- putting some documentation in the code
- Having some generic error handling capability

Having said that, well done, and keep up the work.